# A basic difference between moment generating function and Laplace transform

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have read in a probability book that the advantage of dealing with Laplace transform (for non-negative random variable) rather than moment generating function is that Laplace transform is always between $0$ and $1$. I don't understand what is the advantage ?

Laplace transform is $\phi(-t)$ whereas moment generating function is $\phi(t)$

Answer (score 2):

Moment generating functions are also called two sided Laplace transform. In that, you can say for a random variable $X$, the Laplace transform can be $E[e^{-sX}]$ for $s \geq 0$. The reason that Laplace transform is between $0$ and $1$ is that $0\leq e^{-sX} \leq 1$.

There are obvious advantages of Laplace transforms if you have ever taken a Linear Systems class. Read [this](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1172641.files/laplace.pdf) to gain more insight.

Comment: The link is dead.